# Regex check between two integer values?

Tags: regex

Is there a regular expression check for a number that is within the range of (for example) 18 and 65?

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[18-65]$", ErrorMessage = "Customers must be 
 between the ages of 18 and 65. This is due to our insurance policy.")]
```

Comment: Yes there is. But why regex?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Well, you can check between values of 1 and 100 for example so why not 18 and 65??

Comment: Please don't use a regex to test int ranges. It's more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann What should I use then? (This is for a website by the way)

Comment: Using a regex to check for numeric values is like using a screwdriver to stir paint.  You can do it, but that's not the best tool for the job.

Comment: @BorisSmith regex is an excellent tool for matching but what you want is related to logic. Having a simple if statement like `if n >= 18 and n <= 65` is more readable and is the right approach than using regex to apply logic.  Using regex for this will fall in an ugly expression with long patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?:1[89]|[2-5]\d|6[0-5])$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/121

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a regular expression check for a number that is within the range of (for example) 18 and 65?

Yes, there is. @vks already posted a suggestion. But the question is "should I use a regex for that?".

Regex is not used for matching things like you're trying to. Depends on the language you're using, there are much better alternatives.

`[18-65]` is *invalid* Regex, it tries to match 1, 5 or numbers in range [8,6], since the range is illegal, it's not a valid.